# My Image Slider doesnt show the first picture before I choose the next one

Tags: html, image, css, slider

I've gotten a Image slider there the first photo doesn't show before I got to the next picture. Got any Suggestion on what the problem can be?

Comment: Hi Even, read this. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask At a minimum, we need to see your code with a [mcve], and a description of what you've tried that didn't work is also useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="Second-Section">
            <div class="slideshow-container">
              <div class="Slides fade">
                <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
                <img src="Assets/IMG/e-sport+coaching.jpg" style="width:100%">
                <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
              </div>

              <div class="mySlides fade">
                <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
                <img src="Assets/IMG/e-sport+coaching.jpg" style="width:100%">
                <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
              </div>

              <div class="mySlides fade">
                <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
                <img src="Assets/IMG/e-sport+coaching.jpg" style="width:100%">
                <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
              </div>

              <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
              <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
            </div>
            <br>

            <div style="text-align:center">
              <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
              <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
              <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
            </div>
```